# Add a custom action button to the users' list page that enables staff to set a user to active or inactive with the click of a button

Tags: python, django, django-templates

am building a dashboard basically, presently am trying to add a custom button that allows the staff to set other users to active or inactive, with a click of the button. The main problem now is how to pass the current active state of the user from the html to Django when I click the "SWITCH TO ACTIVE STATE BUTTON "
My views.py looks like this

```
def home(request, username):
  username= User.objects.get(username = username )
  if username.is_active :
        username.is_active = False
        username.save()
    else:
        username.is_active = True
        username.save()
    return HttpResponse ('its state has been changed')
```

my dashboard.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dashboard</title>

     {% load static %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
     <script src="{% static 'js/dashboard.js' %}">
     </script>
</head>
<body>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     Hi {{ user.username }} 
     <br>
     <br>
     <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
  {% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
   {% endif %}
    

   {% for all_users in users %}     
    <li>{{all_users}}
        
       <form action="{% url 'savesttest:home' %}" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="hidden" value={users} >
         <button onclick="handleToggle()" id="switchName" type="submit"> Switch To Active State
        </button>
       </form>
        
    </li>  
    {% endfor %}

<p> this is all {{users}}</p>
    <p>there are {{usersCount}} users in the admin and its presently {{now}}</p>


    <form method="get">
      {{filterUsers.form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
     </form>
     <ul>
        {% for user in filterUsers.qs %}
          <li>{{user}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

while my views.py looks like

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include
from . import views


app_name = 'savesttest'
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name = 'index' ),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), name='accounts'),
    path('index/send_email/', views.send_email, name="send_email"),
    path('signup',views.signup, name='signup' ),
    path('index/send_email_success', views.send_email_success, name="send_email_success")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better served having the active state as a model in the database. With the user model referencing the active state, you can then pass the active state into a form